# R:Why don't functions of two variables accept vectors of length two as inputs?

Tags: r, vector, types

From the gtools library, take `combinations(5,2)`. This gives the following output:

```
> combinations(5,2)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    1    4
 [4,]    1    5
 [5,]    2    3
 [6,]    2    4
 [7,]    2    5
 [8,]    3    4
 [9,]    3    5
[10,]    4    5
```

Storing this as `comb` we can extract rows, e.g. `comb[1,]` which is `1 2`. Now suppose that I want to use `comb[1,]` as an input to a function of two arguments, say `beta(a,b)` (documented [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Special.html)). `beta(1,2)` works just fine, but `beta(comb[1,])` will throw the error `Error in beta(comb[1,]) : argument "b" is missing, with no default`. Why is this? I'm confident that this is a type issue, but R is not a strongly typed language. How could this error be avoided be a user who wants to use something like `beta(comb[1,])`?

Comment: What is `beta` here.  If beta, takes two arguments and if there is no default for 'b', then it will result in error.  If you want to avoid that, there should be a default for beta iin the function.  i.e. `beta <- function(a, b = 10){....}`

Comment: The reason is that `beta(a,b)` takes two arguments, but you only pass it one (a row). If you instead call it as `beta(comb[1,1], comb[1,2])`, it should work.

Comment: @akrun If I'm not mistaken, beta is a function in base R.

Comment: thanks, so `beta` is defined without any default value for 'b' or 'a', so you have to provide both.  I am not sure I understand your question better.  i.e. if you have only provided 'a', then what should be 'b'

Comment: Or is your question to apply the `beta` on the `combinations` output

Comment: @akrun You're quite right that I'm trying to feed one object to a function of two inputs. I'm trying to use the row extracted from the combinations outputs in question as an input to beta.

Comment: Can you check my solutoin below.  Is that you wanted

Comment: `comb[1, ]` is ONE object with a length of TWO. This is different to TWO objects with lengths of ONE. Learning how vectorising works will be fruitful.

Comment: @akrun It looks like an option that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to apply `beta` on the output of `combinations`, one option is to convert it to a `list` and then use `do.call`

```
library(gtools)
do.call(beta, asplit(combinations(5,2), 2))
#[1] 0.500000000 0.333333333 0.250000000 0.200000000 0.083333333 
#[6] 0.050000000 0.033333333 0.016666667 0.009523810 0.003571429
```

Or another option is `apply`

```
apply(combinations(5, 2), 1, FUN = function(x) beta(x[1], x[2]))
```

this would avoid creating any objects

-checking the output with individual entry to `beta`

```
beta(1, 2) #1st row of combinations output
#[1] 0.5
beta(1, 3) # 2nd row of combinations output
#[1] 0.3333333
beta(1, 4) # 3rd row of combinations output
#[1] 0.25
```